# Flavor dimensions and variant filters for experimental plugin?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, gradle-experimental

Does anyone know the syntax for defining flavor dimensions and variant filters using the experimental Gradle plugin? (This would include the syntax for assigning a flavor to a particular dimension inside each flavor's `create()` block.)

The [experimental plugin user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) doesn't address any of this and I couldn't find any examples in the [code samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk). I'm using plugin version 0.2.1 (`com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.1`). The syntax for the regular plugin clearly doesn't work at all.

Here's the original script, which defines product flavors for Google Play and for Amazon AppStore:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.1'

        defaultConfig.with {
            ... // normal stuff
        }
    }
    android.aaptOptions {
        noCompress = 'dict'
    }
    android.ndk {
        ... // normal stuff
    }
    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("google") {
        }
        create("amazon") {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
}
```

Since this app uses native code, I want to add a dimension for different hardware platforms. Also, since the Amazon AppStore and Google Play have different models for supporting different hardware, I want to use variant filters to treat hardware platforms differently for the different markets.

I've <strike>stumbled about blindly in the dark</strike> tried a number of things to define flavor dimensions; **these all generate errors** when compiling the Gradle script.

I haven't tried creating variant filters yet, since I'm stuck at step 1, but absent guidance from someone "in the know", I expect equal (lack of) success.

**Attempt 1:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        ...

        defaultConfig.with {
            ...
            flavorDimensions = ["abi", "market"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Error:

> No such property: flavorDimensions for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor

**Attempt 2:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        ...

        defaultConfig.with {
            ...
        }
        flavorDimensions = ["abi", "market"]
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Error:

> No such property: flavorDimensions for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig

**Attempt 3:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        ... // as in original script
    }
    android.flavorDimensions {
        create("abi") {}
        create("market") {}
    }
}
...
```

Error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > The following model rules are unbound: 
> >         model.android.flavorDimensions
> >           Mutable:
> >             - android.flavorDimensions (java.lang.Object)

**Attempt 4:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        ...
    }
    android.flavorDimensions = ["abi", "market"]
}
```

Error:

> No such property: flavorDimensions for class: org.gradle.model.dsl.internal.NonTransformedModelDslBacking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this issue today. Finally, I found that you don't need to specify android.flavorDimensions. You only need to simply add dimension to each flavors.

I am using experimental experimental plugin 0.2.1 with gradle-2.5.

```
android.productFlavors {
    create("product1"){
        dimension = "product"
    }
    create("product"){
        dimension = "product"
    }
    create("arm"){
        dimension = "abi"
    }
    create("armv7"){
        dimension = "abi"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that works, because it runs contrary to Google's documentation for the main branch plugin. What syntax did you use for assigning dimensions using the experimental plugin?

Comment: @TedHopp "dimension" is the one I am using.

Comment: Okay! That seems to work perfectly well. I guess with the experimental plugin there's no need to declare flavor groups. Do you know anything about creating variant filters with the experimental plugin?

Comment: @TedHopp not really. But, which filter you're referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the `variantFilter` closure as described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Filtering-Variants).

Comment: No longer works with Gradle 4.0, plugin 3.0.0 and experimental 0.11.0-alpha1. Cannot compile without specifying a dimension and above syntax doesn't do the trick anymore.